# Opposite of csname

Tags: macros, definition, csname

If I have a macro `\Name` that expands to a macro name, I can use that with `\csname` or the various tools from etoolbox. Can I do the opposite, i.e., get the name of a macro?

My use case is the following: I want to write a command `\Mtx` that produces a `smallmatrix` (from mathtools). An optional argument should take a delimiter size, and if it is not provided, the size is determined automatically (this deviates slightly from the syntax mathtools' `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` imposes for the commands it defines).

I tried

```tex
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Mtx}{om}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \left(\begin{smallmatrix}#2\end{smallmatrix}\right)
    }{
        #1(\begin{smallmatrix}#2\end{smallmatrix}#1)
    }
}
```

However, I thought it might be advisable to have a provided `\big` for `#1` replaced by `\bigl` and `\bigr`, respectively. Is it advisable?

So, I thought, if there is a command `\GetName` such that `\GetName{\command}` expands to `command`, then I could do:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Mtx}{om}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \left(\begin{smallmatrix}#2\end{smallmatrix}\right)
    }{
        \csuse{\GetName{#1}l}(\begin{smallmatrix}#2\end{smallmatrix}\csuse{\GetName{#1}r})
    }
}
```

Is that possible? I guess someone will point at lacking error handling. But now I'm curious!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's `\cs_to_str:N`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Mtx}{om}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {
        \left(\begin{smallmatrix}#2\end{smallmatrix}\right)
      }
      {
        \use:c {\cs_to_str:N #1 l}(
        \begin{smallmatrix}#2\end{smallmatrix}
        \use:c {\cs_to_str:N #1 r})
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\Mtx{a & b \\ c & d}
\quad
\Mtx[\big]{a & b \\ c & d}
\quad
\Mtx[\Big]{a & b \\ c & d}
\quad
\Mtx[\bigg]{a & b \\ c & d}
\quad
\Mtx[\Bigg]{a & b \\ c & d}
\]

\end{document}
```

Don't use `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, unless you know what you're doing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you also for the remark on `\Declare` vs `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Answer (score 8):

In LuaTeX, we have `\csstring` primitive. If `#1` is `\big`, then

```
\csname \csstring #1l\endcsname
```

is `\bigl`.